# INDEX MATCH VBA (return a value based on two criteria)

Tags: vba, excel, lookup, formulas

I'm doing some work for a client where they receive a weekly report of customers and regions (two columns, A for Customer & B for Region, in a worksheet). * *I've omitted the other columns in this spreadsheet for the sake of clarity*

They need to match the price on this spreadsheet with a reference spreadsheet, which we'll call Prices. Each customer and region combination yields a certain price which is stored on the aforementioned reference spreadsheet (In this reference worksheet [Prices], Column A is the customer, Column B is the region, Column C is the price for A customer in B region).

What I'm trying to do is:

Based on A1(customer) and B1(region), C1 should be (lookupvalue for price on the reference worksheet).

The traditional vlookup function would not work because multiple criteria need to be satisfied (i.e. we may have different prices for the same customer in a different region).

I've tried the below with no success

```
Dim ULastRow As Long
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).UsedRange
ULastRow = sht.UsedRange.Rows(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = _
"=Index(Range("C:C"), Match(Range("Prices!C1"), Range("Prices!C2:B34"), 0), 0)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C2" & ULastRow)
```

See the below links for data examples (Unfortunately I am unable to add them in-line:

What the customer gets: https://copy.com/EBABGl2EFjyFWcIH

The "Prices" or Reference data https://copy.com/oSSJuu7Dk4ox84tz

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly?: You have a worksheet with columns A,B  and C and their respective information. And you want to select the value of C based on A and B?

Comment: Why do you need VBA and not just some lookup functions in Excel?

Comment: You can enter an array formula with index/match to look up based on multiple criteria.  This would be the formula, which you can translate into VBA.  I'm going to just make it up and say you are trying to return something in column F :  `=index(F:F,match(A1&B1,CustomerRange&RegionRange,0))` and enter with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: daZza, great question, I'll clarify in an edit. Thanks!

Comment: Still not entirely sure if I understand your situation correctly :P So you got 1 worksheet where you only have columns A and B and in addition to that you have another worksheet called "Prices" which was columns A, B and C? In that case the first worksheet would be totally useless, because you got all information stored in the "Prices" one. Selecting the C column from that one should work like in my answer below. Did you try that yet?

Comment: @daZza I'm sorry for all the confusion and I really appreciate your assistance with this. That is correct. The first worksheet is what the Client gets (basically a list of all transactions they have had with the client). They need to assign a price to each transaction on this worksheet based on the standard rate on the reference worksheet. Check out the images in the edit and let me know if that helps clear things up. I've tried your answer but I'm unable to get it to work.  Thank you again!

Comment: @Dr.Trey I see. I will edit my answer, just give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imho this is a classic case of "use a database instead of Excel", especially if you want to make these kind of queries regularly.

However, something like this should achieve what you want in VBA:

```
Dim customer As String
Dim region As String
Dim price as Double

For r = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Client").UsedRange.Rows.Count

        customer = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Client").Cells(r, 1).Value
        region = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Client").Cells(r, 2).Value
        price = 0.00

    For s = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Prices").UsedRange.Rows.Count


        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Prices").Cells(s, 1).Value = customer And ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Prices").Cells(s, 2).Value = region Then

            price = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Prices").Cells(s, 3).Value
            Exit For

        End If

    Next

        If price = 0.00 Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Client").Cells(r, 3).Value = "This customer/region combination is not stored in the reference sheet"
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Client").Cells(r, 3).Value = price
        End If
Next
```

Change your worksheet and the starting row (r) accordingly

Comment: Thanks @daZza. I'm getting the error: Compile error: For control variable already in use. If I remove the second for statement, I get the error: "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" for `For r = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Client").UsedRange.Rows.Count`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Guess you copied my statement too fast :P Accidentally didn't change the counter variable after copying the for-clause. This should be fixed now.

For the out of range error: I'm pretty sure that there are rows with "invisible content" below the actual data. That's the downside to using the rather simple `UsedRange.Rows.Count`. Try manually selecting a few rows below the line where the actual data ends and then right click and remove rows. It could also be caused by invalid sheet names (did you change those to your actual ones? You can use numbers instead too)

Comment: Thank you so much!  I got around the out of range error by using a different method of getting the last row: `Dim LastRow As Long
Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).UsedRange
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` and changing `ThisWorkbook` to `ActiveWorkbook`.